# How to reduce repeated elements in a Pandas dataframe with Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a dataframe that looks like this:

```
A                       B           C       D       E   F   G   H
ctg.s1.000000F_arrow    CDS gene    21215   22825   0   +   .   DAFEIOHN_00017
ctg.s1.000000F_arrow    CDS gene    21215   22825   0   +   .   DAFEIOHN_00017
ctg.s1.000000F_arrow    CDS gene    64501   66033   0   -   .   DAFEIOHN_00049
ctg.s1.000000F_arrow    CDS gene    70234   78846   0   +   .   DAFEIOHN_00053
ctg.s1.000000F_arrow    CDS gene    103455  106526  0   +   .   DAFEIOHN_00074
ctg.s1.000000F_arrow    CDS gene    161029  161712  0   +   .   DAFEIOHN_00132
ctg.s1.000000F_arrow    CDS gene    170711  171520  0   +   .   DAFEIOHN_00142
ctg.s1.000000F_arrow    CDS gene    203959  204450  0   -   .   DAFEIOHN_00174
ctg.s1.000000F_arrow    CDS gene    211381  212196  0   +   .   DAFEIOHN_00184
ctg.s1.000000F_arrow    CDS gene    236673  238499  0   +   .   DAFEIOHN_00209
ctg.s1.000000F_arrow    CDS gene    533077  533850  0   +   .   DAFEIOHN_00475
ctg.s1.000000F_arrow    CDS gene    533995  535194  0   +   .   DAFEIOHN_00572
ctg.s1.000000F_arrow    CDS gene    641146  643083  0   +   .   DAFEIOHN_00572
```

As you can see, in the `H` column there are repeated elements like `DAFEIOHN_00017` or `DAFEIOHN_00572`. I'd like to modify this dataframe in order to obtain something like this:

```
A                       B           C       D       E   F   G   H                I
ctg.s1.000000F_arrow    CDS gene    21215   22825   0   +   .   DAFEIOHN_00017   2
ctg.s1.000000F_arrow    CDS gene    64501   66033   0   -   .   DAFEIOHN_00049   1
ctg.s1.000000F_arrow    CDS gene    70234   78846   0   +   .   DAFEIOHN_00053   1
ctg.s1.000000F_arrow    CDS gene    103455  106526  0   +   .   DAFEIOHN_00074   1
ctg.s1.000000F_arrow    CDS gene    161029  161712  0   +   .   DAFEIOHN_00132   1
ctg.s1.000000F_arrow    CDS gene    170711  171520  0   +   .   DAFEIOHN_00142   1
ctg.s1.000000F_arrow    CDS gene    203959  204450  0   -   .   DAFEIOHN_00174   1
ctg.s1.000000F_arrow    CDS gene    211381  212196  0   +   .   DAFEIOHN_00184   1
ctg.s1.000000F_arrow    CDS gene    236673  238499  0   +   .   DAFEIOHN_00209   1
ctg.s1.000000F_arrow    CDS gene    533077  533850  0   +   .   DAFEIOHN_00475   1
ctg.s1.000000F_arrow    CDS gene    533995  535194  0   +   .   DAFEIOHN_00572   2
```

In this second dataframe the repeated elements are shown only one time and there's a new column `I` in which the occurrence of each element of the `H` column is provided.

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to remove rows that are duplicated in a specific column, and use [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to create a new column with values returned from a combination of [`groupby('H')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`transform('count')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) to determine the count of each unique value of `H`:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='H').assign(I=df.groupby('H')['H'].transform('count'))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                       A         B       C       D  E  F  G               H  I
0   ctg.s1.000000F_arrow  CDS-gene   21215   22825  0  +  .  DAFEIOHN_00017  2
2   ctg.s1.000000F_arrow  CDS-gene   64501   66033  0  -  .  DAFEIOHN_00049  1
3   ctg.s1.000000F_arrow  CDS-gene   70234   78846  0  +  .  DAFEIOHN_00053  1
4   ctg.s1.000000F_arrow  CDS-gene  103455  106526  0  +  .  DAFEIOHN_00074  1
5   ctg.s1.000000F_arrow  CDS-gene  161029  161712  0  +  .  DAFEIOHN_00132  1
6   ctg.s1.000000F_arrow  CDS-gene  170711  171520  0  +  .  DAFEIOHN_00142  1
7   ctg.s1.000000F_arrow  CDS-gene  203959  204450  0  -  .  DAFEIOHN_00174  1
8   ctg.s1.000000F_arrow  CDS-gene  211381  212196  0  +  .  DAFEIOHN_00184  1
9   ctg.s1.000000F_arrow  CDS-gene  236673  238499  0  +  .  DAFEIOHN_00209  1
10  ctg.s1.000000F_arrow  CDS-gene  533077  533850  0  +  .  DAFEIOHN_00475  1
11  ctg.s1.000000F_arrow  CDS-gene  533995  535194  0  +  .  DAFEIOHN_00572  2
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use a `groupby` and count the element like so :

```py
df.groupby('H').count()
```